# How to include only a single property when using 'expand'

Tags: breeze

I have an orders table which I want to query.  One of the properties is "UserId" and which turns into a navigation property to the User.

I can query this to get the order and the associated User.  However, I don't want the entire User entity, only the UserName property.

How do I construct that query in breeze?

Something like:

```
let query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
            .from("orders")
            .expand("user.userName");
```

I tried this, but then returned objects are not actually entities, but it does return just the userName:

```
let query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
            .from("cases")
            .select("field1, field2, user.userName");
```

Is there any other way of doing this? Note that I am using EF on the backside.

Comment: I ended up creating a view for the User table with only the Id and Username and related that as needed.

Comment: Yeah, the other way I do this when I can't change the server side is to make a separate projection query to create a client-only column in the entity.  You can iterate through the orders and fire off a projection query for each one `.from('users').where('userId','eq',order.userId).select('userName')` and in the .then `order.userName=data.results[0].userName`

Comment: I call that "backfilling" :)

Comment: So it is.  A necessary evil, I guess.  Would be nice to have both projections and filtering for navigation properties, but I certainly don't begrudge them their priorities.   Nice to have a time- and complexity-saving library like that to work with

Comment: Yes, Agreed.  Breeze is a great product - could not live without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found for this is creating a "virtual entity" which consists of just the two fields that I want.  In other words, I have AspNetUsers as one table with it's corresponding entity.  And then I have a second code first entity which consists of only the Id, and the UserName:

```
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public string AspNetUserId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

I can then use it as a relation in other tables and include it like was just another table.